# Syntax highlighting rule doesn't work when a another highlight (# comment) exists

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to create a highlight that changes the text color of a strikethrough syntax, like `~~hello~~` should turn the whole thing gray.

Here's what I've put in my vimrc:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.n syntax match StrikeoutMatch /\~\~.*\~\~/
hi def StrikeoutColor ctermbg=0 ctermfg=15 guibg=0 guifg=15
hi link StrikeoutMatch StrikeoutColor
```

This mostly works - in a file named `test.n` if the content is the following, then the `~~test~~` is correctly highlighted:

```
~~test~~
hello what's up
```

But, in the following case, the `~~test~~` text does not get highlighted - instead, `# test` is highlighted (as a comment):

```
# test
~~test~~
```

If I open a file without a `#` comment and then type a `# test`, that line is not highlighted. When I relaunch vim into that file it swaps to highlight `#` and not the `~~`.

What I want is for the `~~test~~` syntax to not interfere with anything else. I should be able to write that in any file matching the `.n` extension, while other things like `#` still get highlighted as usual. Would really appreciate some guidance on how to accomplish this.

Some images:

1. Opened a file with the `# test` comment already there. ~~test~~ is not highlighted, 3rd line is highlighted on the fly as I typed it
   [image]
2. File originally with just the one `~~test~~` line. I typed the `#` comment, which is not highlighted, and then typed the 3rd line which is highlighted

[image]

3. Closed and re-opened the file from above. Highlights have swapped
   [image]
4. Deleting the comment line doesn't help
   [image]
5. But once I've deleted the comment line, I can close and re-open the file and it works again.
   [image]

Comment: I would first try looking in `:help contains` and `:help containedin`, as that *might* be an avenue to explore for solutions.  I tried reproducing your error, but could not.  Is `#` as a comment *only* for a single line?

Comment: Oh ok, will look into those. I was hoping that it was some default behavior haha.. Yes, the `#` comment is just one line. I just edited my question with some screenshots to more clearly illustrate the behavior if that helps.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you check what the filetype is after you go through the 1-5 steps since you open and close things?  `set ft?` to check it.  I wonder if adding the `#` on the first line is making vim think the filetype is `sh`, and that's why you get different behavior when you open, save, close, and reopen? Maybe?

Comment: That seems to be related! With a `#` I get `filetype=conf`. Without it I get a blank `filetype=`. However, it seems that it doesn't matter what line it's on - adding a line starting with `#` anywhere causes `filetype` to become `conf`. I'm also unsure how to manually specify the alternative blank option because `set ft=`, which does result in `filetype=` from `set ft?`, does not also fix the highlighting (`set ft=conf` does change the highlighting immediately to match the usual `#` `conf` case).

Comment: Update: so... moving the config commands to the end of my vimrc seems to have fixed all this! Now even with `filetype=conf` the highlighting is correct (both the `#` and `~~` lines are highlighted). Probably should've tried that earlier!

Comment: Good to hear!  I'd check out Maxim Kim's response because he has what looks like the full explanation of what is happening and he has a better fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is filetype detection vim uses to autodetect filetype and set proper syntax:

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/004d9b00ba600a167746ad7af88e0baa77c95d8f/runtime/filetype.vim#L2243

Your autocommand is run before the filetype detection (where you add some syntax). Then filetype detection finds out this looks like `conf` file and current filetype is not set -- it sets `conf` filetype, overriding your syntax.

For me it looks like you need to create a new filetype with syntax (filetype detection will not override it).

Non-suggested way to do it is (following your code snippet):

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.n set ft=n | call SetupNSyntax()

func! SetupNSyntax()
    syntax match StrikeoutMatch /\~\~.*\~\~/
    hi StrikeoutColor ctermbg=0 ctermfg=15 guibg=NONE guifg=#7777f7
    hi def link StrikeoutMatch StrikeoutColor
endfunc
```

Suggested way is it create a separate syntax file in `~/.vim/syntax/n.vim`:

```
syntax match StrikeoutMatch /\~\~.*\~\~/
hi StrikeoutColor ctermbg=0 ctermfg=15 guibg=NONE guifg=#7777f7
hi def link StrikeoutMatch StrikeoutColor
```

and add filetype detection in `~/.vim/ftdetect/n.vim`

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.n set ft=n
```

`:h new-filetype` for reference.

PS, when vim sets filetype that is in `ftplugin/somefiletype.vim` file, it will also call the syntax file with the same name `syntax/somefiletype.vim`. More to it, you can only have a syntax file `syntax/somefiletype.vim` -- setting filetype with `:set filetype=somefiletype` will apply syntax with the same base filename.

PPS, your `hi` definition looks wrong to me:

```
hi def StrikeoutColor ctermbg=0 ctermfg=15 guibg=0 guifg=15
```

in Gui vim it errors with "cannot allocate color 0".

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough and informative answer! Will do as you suggested, it certainly seems more organized.